# AWK switch case not matching *.html

Tags: regex, awk, switch-statement

I don't understand what I was doing wrong.

I tried the following (what I thought the simplest and most direct), but it would not match the filename string passed by **outfile** (**Text/content_001_One.html**):

```
switch( outfile ){
    case *.html :
        doctype="application/xhtml+xml" ;
        break;
    default : ;
} ;
```

I also tried (still without success):

```
switch( outfile ){
    case /*.html/ :
    case /*.html$/ :
    case /*[.]html/ :
        doctype="application/xhtml+xml" ;
        break;
    default : ;
} ;
```

I was forced to resort to this

```
n=split( outfile, pathName, "." ) ;
printf("\t\t Suffix of outfile => %s ...\n", pathName[n] ) | "cat 1>&2" ;
switch( pathName[n] ){
    case "html" :
        doctype="application/xhtml+xml" ;
        break;
    default : ;
} ;
```

I would prefer to use the outfile value directly instead of the workaround.

Can someone please show me what the correct form would be?

Comment: Recall that in RegEx (not file globbing) `*` means "zero or more of the previous character", you need `.*\.html` probably. Good luck.

Comment: `*` as the first character in a regexp is undefined behavior per POSIX so YMMV with what any awk would do with that.

Comment: You are referring a _[glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))_.  Same concept, although it is not, specifically, a _"regular expression pattern"_.

Comment: If you want to match a string that ends in `foo` just write `foo$`. Adding `.*` in a regexp (or `*` in a globbing pattern) in front of `foo` is pointless unless you wanted to **capture** the matching string to do something with it, which you don't.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a string that *ends* in `.html` one viable regex is `/\.html$/`, eg:

```
switch( outfile ){
    case /\.html$/ :
        doctype="application/xhtml+xml" ;
        break;
    default : ;
} ;
```

Comment: It seems that I don't fully understand the difference between regexp and globbing.  I need to dig into that and get it sorted out in my mind for good.